# Is it possible to install SAP B1 SDK on Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: sapb1

Is it possible to install SAP B1 SDK on Visual Studio 2017 ? If Yes? how ?

I tried changing registry for VS 2017 but i could not find it.

Answer (score 3):

Try this..

1. Close all your Visual Studio instances.
2. Open windows registry typing the command below on run window:
   `regedit`
3. Go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio on registry tree view.
4. Rename folders (keys) started with 15.0 to 10.0 for B1 Setup understand the structure.
5. Install B1 Studio for MS Visual Studio.
6. Go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio on registry
   tree view again.
7. Rename folders (keys) started with 10.0 to 15.0.
8. Open Visual Studio 2017.
9. Go to File > New Project > Templates > Visual C# and check if SAP Business One templates are installed.

*If you have an installation of visual studio 2010, you need to rename the registry folders started with 10.0 to OLD_10.0 and after you finish the steps above you must rename then to previous name.

Comment: When i open registry there is 5 different version entries, see screenshot: https://s15.postimg.org/nnbe3uq23/image.png

Comment: So, these are entries from old visual studio versions. Try to rename all of them adding an underline for example and then rename the key 15.0 to 10.0 according to the tutorial.

Comment: Where to download B1 Studio for MS Visual Studio?

Comment: It comes in the SAP B1 installation package. And I think you can download it from the SAP PartnerEdge potal.

Comment: With B1 9.3 PL04 and VS Community 2017, this doesn't seem to work for me. :-(

Comment: Sorry guys, but this is not working with the current version of visual studio 2017. Now I have two VS installed, 2015 and 2017 ;)

Answer (score 0):

The best way is install SAP BO on your PC, you have to be shure that yo are installing the SDK, when the installation are done, open your VS project and add a reference to COM libraries and import UI API and DI API.

Comment: The SAP B1 SDK is not just the `SAPBusinessOneSDK.dll`, but also contains project templates, and UI controls, among some other things. Merely including the dll is ok for DI API usage, but addon development is improved with the full SDK.

Answer (score 0):

SAP B1 10.0 PL4 supports Visual studio 2019. So you can just install SAP B1 Studio from 10.0 PL4 version if you don't want to update SBO.